# Prove that k-regular graph is also k-edge-connected

Tags: graph-theory

We have graph G which is k-regular. If such condition is met, we want to (dis)prove that graph G is also k-edge-connected. It seems so clear and obvious to me I'd bet it's true, but I can't really help myself with creating some resolute proof on it. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are looking for connected graphs and not just like $K_n \oplus K_n$.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing some conditions, because as T.Gunn's example below shows it is not true as currently written, but it could be made true by adding a few more conditions, such as $k\geq \frac{n}{2}$ where $n$ is the number of vertices: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281001/is-a-graph-with-minimum-degree-delta-delta-edge-connected?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 regular, only 2 edge connected:

[image]

Comment: It's enough for me you showed it's not true.